# Running a process of one terminal in backgound using (ctrl + z) and then using other shell to access it

Tags: linux, shell

I am having a process which will be running in background of my terminal one. Am doing this by signal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>), hence this process will be suspended. And if I close this terminal, my process will be still in wait state(unterminated).

Now I am willing to access this process as a foreground process in my new terminal.

Aim for above producer is that I want to access same process in continues without terminating this process. No shell script is used.
Is it possible to do so?
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question and add a tag for the OS used.

Comment: In unix shells you usually have `bg` to continue the stopped process in the background.

Comment: You can't resume a stopped job in a different shell session.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using a unix like os (ctrl+z to suspend), try using the tmux or screen utilities.